# Create a DLL in VC++ for VB 4.0

Tags: c++

I'm creating a DLL in Visual C++ 1.5 for use from Visual Basic 4.0 (I'm working on 16-bit Windows 95). One function I created receives a string and returns another string, the parameter declaration is:

```
NPSTR CALLBACK __ export (NPSTR chain)
{
    ....
}
```

I have also tested with LPSTR and char *.

In Visual Basic do's statement as a string using ByVal parameter As String function but VC + + does not receive chain and when I run the VB program gives me an error saying that the types do not match.

What is the correct declaration statement to receive a string of Visual Basic and return another? 
When I return whole step and there is no problem. 
I would also like to know what would be the way to pass an array.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the issue of "how to declare such a function", the problem with your DLL function is that it should *not* return a string from the DLL, unless it is a pointer to the original string that was passed.

Most, if not all Windows API functions that handle strings do so in this manner:

1. The caller to the DLL function is responsible for creating the string/buffer, including having it sized appropriately before calling the function.
2. The caller provides as another argument, the maximum length of the buffer that was passed.

On the DLL side, the DLL does as follows:

1. The DLL function gets the information it is asked for in a local string variable (this could be a character array, a std::string, doesn't matter, as this is internal to the DLL).
2. The DLL function then copies this string information to the passed-in buffer, respecting the passed-in maximum size given by the caller.  So if the string information is really 1,000 bytes, but the user passed 100 as the maximum buffer size, then you copy only 99 (or 100) characters.
3. The DLL function returns the number of characters copied.  This can be used by the caller to resize their buffer to the actual size if it is discovered that the original passed-in buffer was large (Note that handling terminating NULLs is a contract you must make between the callers to your function and the DLL function, so I didn't go into detail here as to whether you should copy a NULL or not at the end.)
4. In addition, the DLL could also return the total number of characters needed to store the entire string information.  Usually for this to happen, the DLL function has a special "mode" it can work in if the output string is NULL.  If the output string is NULL, the DLL function would still get the information, but will not copy it to the output buffer, and instead, return the total number of characters.  So the caller would make two calls to the DLL function, once to determine how many characters the information will be so that the caller resizes their buffer accordingly, and the second call to the DLL function would be the actual call that copies the characters to the buffer.

That is basically in a nutshell how it works.  If your function requires an input string and an output string, then your function should change to something like this:

```
LONG CALLBACK __ export SomeDLLFunction(NPSTR strIn, NPSTR strOut, LONG maxOutSize)
```

Now on the VB side:

```
Public Declare Function SomeDLLFunction Lib "YourDLL" (ByVal strIn As String, ByVal strOut As String, ByVal strMaxLen As Long) As Long
```

Now, the reason why Windows does things this way is that the DLL function no longer 
returns a pointer or reference to a local variable (which is undefined behavior), and no longer needs to figure out how to dynamically create a string (which would then need some module to deallocate the string, and also know exactly *how* to deallocate the string, i.e. what function to call to do this -- that's a pain in the neck).

Everything is reliant on the caller to provide the buffer and the maximum size of the buffer to write to.

Answer (score 1):

Take the example of `GetHostByName` function:

```
// C
struct hostent* FAR gethostbyname(
  _In_  const char *name
);

// VB
Public Declare Function gethostbyname 
    Lib "ws2_32.DLL" (ByVal host_name As String) As Long
```

You can use:

```
const char* CALLBACK __ export (const char* chain)
{
    ....
}
```

and in VB declarations:

```
// VB
Public Declare Function functionname 
    Lib "yourdll.DLL" (ByVal chain As String) As String
```